# Set file permissions, exclude folder - doesn't work with chmod (works with chown?)

Tags: permissions, chmod

I want to change file permissions and exclude a folder and it's contents (or only the contents is okay too).

It doesn't seem to work the same way as with chown - beause with chown I can change owner and exklude a folder like this:

```
sudo find . ! \( -path './images' -o -path './images/*' \)  -exec chown 33:33 {} \;
```

But when I try to change permissions with the same syntax:

```
sudo find . ! \( -path '/home/myuser/testdir/three/uploads/*' -o -path 
'/home/myuser/testdir/three/uploads' \) -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

That folder was not excluded, all files were affected.
And it's not because of the added "`-type f`", that works with
the chown command too.

So I'm wondering what I need to change to make it work with the `chmod` command?

Answer (score 2):

This problem does not result from the `chmod` command but from your `find` expressions.

In your working example you tests like `-path './images'` that match the starting directory `.`, while in your non-working command you use absolute paths for `-path` with the same relative starting directory.

To see what files match your expressions, run

```
sudo find . ! \( -path '/home/myuser/testdir/three/uploads/*' -o -path 
'/home/myuser/testdir/three/uploads' \) -type f -print
```

I suggest to omit all exclude patterns first and then add exclude patterns that actually match the printed paths of the files.

In general, if you want to execute a command that will change something on your system, you should test the `find` command with `-print` first until you get the expected list of files before you add the `-exec` action.

---

Another option would be to use a matching start directory, e.g.

```
sudo find /home/myuser/testdir ! \( -path '/home/myuser/testdir/three/uploads/*' -o -path 
'/home/myuser/testdir/three/uploads' \) -type f -print
```